# libcurl C++: which parameters to listen to when checking if a webpage has been updated?

Tags: c++, curl, web-scraping, https, libcurl

I've recently been using `libcurl` to detect when a particular web page has been updated by listening for a change in the page's `HTTPS status code` by employing `CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE`.

However, I am attempting to retrieve newly uploaded data from a different webpage now, but its `HTTPS status code` stays the same at `200` even when the page has been updated with new information.

As such, are there any other parameters that can be monitored to notify as quickly as possible that there has been a change in the content of a page? Initially, I thought about counting the number of bytes in the page when it's returned via my libcurl function, and then checking if the next response's byte length is different (hence, signalling that some new content has been added to the page).

This is a time-sensitive application however, and this method of counting the number of bytes and making a comparison for every request-response may not be the best approach in terms of latency, and also may not be particularly accurate (e.g. maybe an aspect in the header such as a "hit/miss from cloudfront" could result in a different page length size, even though there isn't any new front-end content uploaded).

**Summary question:**

Are there any parameters (perhaps in the response header?) other than the `HTTPS status code` that can be monitored with `libcurl` to check if a page has been updated with any new content, as quickly as possible?

Comment: Maybe a `HTTP HEAD` request is what you need? https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_NOBODY.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have been using `HEAD` requests, but I'm looking more for the parameters within that request that may change, thus notifying me of updated content.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [If-Modified-Since](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/If-Modified-Since) in HTTP protocol.